# Azure Function App Service Bus subscription triggered not consuming messages

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I implemented an Azure Function App with a service bus subscription trigger. It works all well in my laptop debugging it from Visual Studio, getting triggered every time a message is pushed to the service bus topic. However, after deploying it to Azure, it is not triggered when a message is published to the service bus topic.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging and research, I found that it was working well locally as it was using a emulated storage account; however, in the cloud, it needs to have a storage account. In my case, the problem was that the configuration settings were missing the details for the storage account. It needs to be either a connection string setting (if you are using SAS tokens), or as in my case, the two following entries, as I use managed identities instead (why it needed both representations is still unclear to me):

```
{
  "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage:accountName",
  "value": "yourstorageaccountname",
  "slotSetting": false
},
{
  "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName",
  "value": "yourstorageaccountname",
  "slotSetting": false
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be deploying it a Linux plan? If that's the case, you have to use the "__" notation instead of ":" for nested settings and you shouldn't need both.